# regex findall pattern that doesnt contain another pattern - Python

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, match, findall

I am trying to findall the matching patterns from a string but without containing the same pattern as a substring. What I need to do is, findall pattern that matches to <.*:.*> ,without any nested tag(same pattern) after the ':'.

This is the input string,

```
<First tag:Some text<Second tag:Text for second tag>Some other tag<Third tag:Text for third tag>Remaining text
```

Expected output,

```
['<Second tag:Text for second tag>','<Third tag:Text for third tag>']
```

One more input string,

```
<First tag:Some text<Second tagText for second tag>Some other tag<Third tag:Text for third tag>Remaining text
```

Output,

```
['<First tag:Some text<Second tagText for second tag>','<Third tag:Text for third tag>']
```

I tried this way

```
re.findall('\<[^\<.*:.*\>]+:[^\<.*:.*\>]+\>', input_string)
```

This passes in the first example input, but fails in the second one.
Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want match : `<First tag:Some text<Second tagText for second tag>`

you could try : `\<[^\<.*:\>]+:[^.*:\>]+\>`.
It will fullfill the two example.

see:
https://regex101.com/r/nU6nO8/4
for detail.

Comment: the regex can be as simple as **[`<[^<:>]+:[^:>]+>`](https://regex101.com/r/nU6nO8/5)**